# Loading all data to Message object

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Is there way to load all email data to `Message` object that will work after closing `Folder` and `Store`?
I've tried copying by `MimeMessage` constructor, but then I do not have received date in new object:

```
Message message = inbox.getMessages()[0];
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage((MimeMessage)message);
msg.getReceivedDate(); // <- always null
```

I've tried to use `FetchProfile`, but opened `Folder` is still needed.

I have to process some emails. Unfortunately it can take some time, so I must have option to do it without opened `Folder`.

Comment: what is assigned to message?

Comment: What do you mean by assigned?

Comment: the code above what you pasted. message = ?

Comment: See @update.
It's loaded object from imap account by Folder#getMessages() or by search.

Comment: debug and find out if Message message = inbox.getMessages()[0]; is null, if so, keep working back until you find your point of failure.

Comment: I know it's not null. There is no problem with initial loading. I have problem with working on lazy Message object.

Comment: I think you're going to need to debug it or show more code mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MimeMessage copy constructor will copy the content of the message and give you a MimeMessage object you can access after the Folder is closed, but if you want the metadata associated with the message, such as the flags and the received date, you'll need to save them yourself explicitly.  You should also think about the memory usage of copying the entire message into local memory.

Comment: Do I have to do it by hand? Or there is way to copy them all at once? I know about memory footprint, but later I am parsing them to internal format.

Comment: You have to do it by hand.